# How do I trigger an Angular custom filter on click and populate with the filtered data?

Tags: angularjs

I want that the .prerequisites container be shown and populated only when the .popPrereq link(which can become a button) is clicked.

The json data is already available in the main controller and the filter works fine. I just need a way to tell angular to populate the data on click.

```
<a href="#" data-ng-show="course.CoursePrerequisites" class="popPrereq">Prerequisites</a>

<div class="prerequisites" style="background:pink">

    <div class="prerequisite" data-ng-repeat="prerequisite in courses | getPrerequisites:course.CoursePrerequisites">
        <p>{ {prerequisite.ProgramCode} } <br> <b>{ {prerequisite.pagetitle} }</b></p>
    </div>

</div>
```

here is my custom filter

```
coursesSearchApp.filter('getPrerequisites', function(){
    return function(prerequisites, ids){

        var searchIds = ids.split(',');
        var arrayToReturn = [];

        for (var i=0; i<prerequisites.length; i++){
            if (searchIds.indexOf(prerequisites[i].id) != -1) {
                arrayToReturn.push(prerequisites[i]);
            }
        }

        return arrayToReturn;
    };
});
```

Thank you

Comment: you can pass another parameter to the filter, which should be set on click and change logic in filter accordingly

Comment: You already have that data somewhere, say `var courses` so on click, just do: $scope.courses = courses;

Comment: or use a flag and `ng-show` , numerous ways to do this...get creative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to the `popPrereq` hyperlink `ngClick` directive where set show/hide status for prerequisites container to true. And add `ngIf` directive with this flag value to the prerequisites.

```
<a href="#" data-ng-show="course.CoursePrerequisites" 
  data-ng-click="showPrerequisites = true"
  class="popPrereq">Prerequisites</a>

<div data-ng-if="showPrerequisites" class="prerequisites" style="background:pink">

  <div class="prerequisite" data-ng-repeat="prerequisite in courses | getPrerequisites:course.CoursePrerequisites">
    <p>{ {prerequisite.ProgramCode} }
      <br> <b>{ {prerequisite.pagetitle} }</b>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: could you also advise on hiding if checked a second time, like a toggle. I will look at ng-if see if there is an else or something. Thanks

Comment: try this: `data-ng-click="showPrerequisites = !showPrerequisites"`